# PHP include form trouble

Tags: php, html, forms, include

I am having trouble with [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) includes, and I am not entirely sure I am using them correctly. What I have so far is an [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) page that I want to add a search bar to. My PHP code in the HTML page looks like this.

```
<?php include 'site/tools/search.php'; ?>
```

The problem I am having is that the search bar is not displaying on the HTML page. I know that the search bar works, because I have browsed to that file location and worked with the actual search bar.

Comment: `What I have so far is an html page that I want to add a search bar too,` -- wrong. Your current page should be `.php`

Comment: are you sure the path is correct?  Also,....post your search bar code if you can

Comment: or simply add this to your htaccess `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use PHP code in HTML documents. Change the extension of your .html file to .php and it should work without affecting anything. This would mean any links to the page would have to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Check that your file ends with .php (not .html) and everything should work (your include statement is correct). If this fails, try using an absolute [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

Answer (score 0):

Use the complete path to the file with your include statement. Like so:
`<?php include '/home/yourusername/public_html/site/tools/search.php';`

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with the path of the file. If you are using a relative path try adding "./" in the begginning like this: "./site/tools/search.php"